# Creating Scripts from a Template in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a text file - it's a template that I want to alter and save as a another file (in this case a markdown file, but it doesn't matter):

`my_test.txt:`

```
---
title: My report
---

$my_var
```

As you can see there is a placeholder `$my_var` - I want to read in the file as a string and then put it the value of the variable `my_var`. How can I do this?

I already tried several things around this:

```
using Chain

my_var = "some string"

@chain begin
    read("my_test.txt", String) # read the text file as a string
    "\"\"\"" * _ * "\"\"\"" # wrap the string with triple quotes
    Meta.parse # parse...
    eval # ...and eval
    write_to_file("reports/jmd_files/org_$(org_id).jmd") # write it to a markdown file
end
```

It does not work though. I tried a lot of variants and I either get an error saying `my_var does not exist` or the value that gets inserted is `nothing` (which is not what it is supposed to be.

So, it really seems to be about the environment in which this is executed, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

---

It shouldn't be important, but just to be sure - eventually want this to run in a loop or in a (to-be-broadcasted) function. So, hard-coding for the single example would not really be a solution.

Comment: Also, I really don't know if the question title is really helpful, but I couldn't come up with something better. Got a suggestion? - Let me know.

Comment: You might be looking for Fmt.jl https://github.com/bicycle1885/Fmt.jl

Comment: Hm, if this hints towards a solution, I do not get it. Would you mind making it an answer with a small example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're looking for a text templating engine like [Mustache.jl](https://github.com/jverzani/Mustache.jl). Eg:

```
using Mustache 

function createscript()
  vars = Dict("my_var" => "some string")
  # Doesn't have to be a Dict - see the docs for other 
  # options eg. a module name can be passed 
  # to grab variables from it

  open("data/rendered.jmd", "w") do out
    render(out, read("data/reporttemplate.mustache", String), vars)
  end
end
```

with `reporttemplate.mustache` containing:

```
---
title: My report
---

{{my_var}}
```

Using a text-templating engine is a lot safer and less error prone than an `eval`.

Comment: Yess. This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Who would have thought that others had this problem before the. I didn't try it, yet, but thank you already.

Answer (score 0):

Not actually an answer to your question but.. are you sure you want to do it ? What you are describing looks like creating a dynamic document, but there are already lots of packages for that.
For example, [Documenter.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDocs/Documenter.jl) and [Weave.jl](https://github.com/JunoLab/Weave.jl) both take markdown documents with embedded Julia scripts and are designed to run the document and compile it in HTML or PDF pages showing the script or its outputs (you choose).

I prefer going a step further and I start from a (valid) Julia script where the markdown structure is embedded with an extra comment layer (e.g. `# ## This would be an H2 header`) and then use [`Literate.jl`](https://github.com/fredrikekre/Literate.jl) to transform it to a markdown with embedded Julia and `Documenter.jl` to create a navigable web site.
These packages have plenty of options and integrate easily with CI like GitHub actions.

Comment: So, what I want is the following: every week I want to create reports - this week 3 reports, next week 4 other ones. I do not know all the reports in advance. So, I need to create the `jmd` files on-the-fly. And these `jmd` files need to be different (of course - otherwise it would be the same report several times). The are different because I make them different and I try to do that by inserting strings programmatically.

Comment: I guess that the report "changes" because some input data to your report changes, for example, this week you analysing data "week43.csv"  and next week "data44.csv" So, make a wave "template" and then either symlink/copy-paste your week-specific data to something like "currentweek.csv" or put the information on the data that change on a place you can easily programmatically edit like "dataInputFiles.txt", or, if you change also the code from one report to the next, you can keep the code that doesn't change in the wave file and include the report-specific code that changes..